# Logo is not appearing in magento site

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-layout-xml

may be you have seen many time this question. I have also surfed alot. But could not find the answer. My problem is that my logo is not appearing in my magento site. I have inserted the logo in

> system > configuration > General > custom logo

But logo is no appearing in my browser. I had cleaned caches. And when i inspected in chrome it showed the path of the logo image is incomplete. it written as

> http://example.in/skin/frontend/default/shoe_store/

But if I am correct it should be

> http://example.in/skin/frontend/default/shoe_store/images/logo.png

Why is it so? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `System > configuration > design >header > logo`

Comment: There I want to specify the image location ie: images/logo.png. right?

Comment: Right image/your log